# ForkJoinPool result never arrived

Tags: java, forkjoinpool

Hi I am new to Java concurrency and I am trying to Double the List Content by fork join and dividing the task into multiple parts.
The task gets Completed but result never arrived.

```
package com.learning;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class DoubleNumbers extends RecursiveTask<List<Integer>> {
    private final List<Integer> listToDo;
    public DoubleNumbers(List<Integer> list) {
        System.out.println("Cons Called"+list.get(0));
        this.listToDo = list;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Integer> compute() {
        List<DoubleNumbers> doubleNumbersList= new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < listToDo.size(); i++) {
            listToDo.set(i, listToDo.get(i) * 2);
        }
        return listToDo;
    }
}

public class FJPExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 149; i++) {
            arrayList.add(i, i);
        }
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(4);

        System.out.println(forkJoinPool.getParallelism());
        DoubleNumbers doubleNumbers = new DoubleNumbers(arrayList.subList(0, 49));
        DoubleNumbers doubleNumbers50ToNext = new DoubleNumbers(arrayList.subList(50, 99));
        DoubleNumbers doubleNumbers100ToNext = new DoubleNumbers(arrayList.subList(100, 149));
        forkJoinPool.submit(doubleNumbers);
        forkJoinPool.execute(doubleNumbers50ToNext);
        forkJoinPool.execute(doubleNumbers100ToNext);
        do {
            System.out.println("Parallel " + forkJoinPool.getParallelism());
            System.out.println("isWorking" + forkJoinPool.getRunningThreadCount());
            System.out.println("isQSubmission" + forkJoinPool.getQueuedSubmissionCount());
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //
            }
        } while ((!doubleNumbers.isDone()) || (!doubleNumbers50ToNext.isDone()) || (!doubleNumbers100ToNext.isDone()));
        forkJoinPool.shutdown(); // Line 56

        arrayList.addAll(doubleNumbers.join());  
        arrayList.addAll(doubleNumbers50ToNext.join());
        arrayList.addAll(doubleNumbers100ToNext.join());
        System.out.println(arrayList.size());
        arrayList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

If I debug my task then I am able to find the numbers gets doubled but the result never arrived at line no 56

Comment: That's not how `ForkJoinPool` is intended to be used; you do all the management from the outside. What you want to do is implement a `ForkJoinTask` that does the splitting of the work itself and then forking and joining accordingly. As a note, since you say you're new to Java concurrency, it would be more worth your while to get a hang on `ExecutorService`s and `CompletableFuture`s before going into `ForkJoinPool` (which I personally have never used nor really seen the point of tbh).

Comment: @daniu What If I have to double the numbers using fork-join. Is there any other approach

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with the code `arrayList.addAll(doubleNumbers.join())` , line# 54, 55 and 56 because this may result into ConcurrentModificationException. So, what you can do is, replace these lines with below lines and it will work(it will work because you have used arrayList.subList at line #36 which is backed by same arraylist, read its javadoc for more info)

```
doubleNumbers.join();
doubleNumbers50ToNext.join();
doubleNumbers100ToNext.join();
```